# I am getting an error while using left join with group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find out a band which doesn't have any album .

**This is my table structure**:

```
CREATE TABLE bands (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE albums (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  release_year INT,
  band_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES bands(id)
);
```

**This is the query:**

```
SELECT bands.name AS 'Band Name' ,count(albums.band_id) AS ALBUMS FROM bands 
JOIN albums ON bands.id = albums.band_id
GROUP BY albums.band_id
HAVING count(albums.band_id) = 0;
```

**Error :**

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'record_company.bands.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error Code: 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'record_company.bands.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: #1 - `albums.band_id` is not primary key column. Use `GROUP BY bands.id`. #2 - `albums.band_id` cannot be NULL, so use `COUNT(*)  AS albums`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT bands.name AS 'Band Name' , COUNT(albums.id) AS ALBUMS 
FROM bands
LEFT JOIN albums ON bands.id = albums.band_id
GROUP BY bands.name
HAVING count(albums.band_id) = 0;
```

As you have `bands.name` in SELECT expression which is with an aggregated function COUNT, you need to GROUP BY `bands.name`.

Let me know if this works?

Comment: its not working now it just returns the column Band name and ALBUMS with no data i need to perform a left join to get the correct output not join

Comment: I have modified the query, is it working?